# How to use session attribute value to execute query get and set data

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm working on a project and i need help ,im working on 'InventoryOfDevicesF1F2' view object (VO) and i get the value of SERIAL_NUMBER attribute from session scope,
so my quatation is i need to pass this value 'SERIAL_NUMBER' to the Maintenance and do the query and get the query and set it on InventoryOfDevicesF1F2 table.
i hope all of you get my point..
this is my query from table that i use:
1/

```
SELECT InventoryOfDevicesF1F2.SERIAL_NUMBER, 
      InventoryOfDevicesF1F2.DEVICE_NO, 
      InventoryOfDevicesF1F2.DEVICE, 
      InventoryOfDevicesF1F2.MODEL_NUMBER
FROM  INVENTORY_OF_DEVICES_F1_F2 InventoryOfDevicesF1F2
```

2/

```
SELECT Maintenance.SERIAL_NUMBER, 
Maintenance.DEVICE_NO, 
Maintenance.DEVICE,
Maintenance.MODEL_NUMBER
FROM  MAINTENANCE Maintenance
```

3/

```
SELECT SwUsers.USERNAME, 
       SwUsers.PASSWORD,
       SwUsers.SERIAL_NUMBER
FROM  SW_USERS SwUsers
```

Answer (score 2):

Please create ViewLink between ViewObjects based on 'SERIAL_NUMBER' column and ensure that current row is set in 'SwUsers' VO , so that all the child data will be filtered automatically based on 'SERIAL_NUMBER' column .